# R quantile of a data frame is giving me "undefined columns selected"

Tags: r, dataframe

I've created a data frame like so:

```
> df <- data.frame(1:20)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ X1.20: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Now, I would like to compute a quantile, but I am getting an error saying "undefined columns selected". What should I do to fix this?

```
> quantile(df, 0.25)
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected

> quantile(df[1], 0.25)
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

On the other hand, if my data is a vector, then quantile() works correctly. What gives?

```
> v <- 1:20
> str(v)
 int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
> quantile(v, 0.25)
 25% 
5.75
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In function `quantile(x, ...)`
x in supposed to be a numeric vector, you are passing a data frame.

If you are using a data frame in quantile function, then you should pass something like this

```
quantile(df$X1.20, 0.25)
```

where `X1.20` is the column name.

In fact, `df[1]` is also a data frame, not a vector.

Comment: Ok, got it. quantile(df[,1], 0.25) produces the correct result. But I don't understand what the expression df[1] produce? It looks like a vector when it prints out.

Comment: Why does quantile() take a vector and not a data.frame? The other stats functions like mean() and var() can take a data.frame.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 `var` will accept a data frame and return a sensible result only if all variables are numeric. `mean` will return `NA` with a warning on a data frame.