# R Quantiles of matrix - wrong output

Tags: r, matrix, output, quantile

I am probably making some easy mistake here but I have a matrix, and I want to produce the quantiles of the whole matrix. I've tried this:

```
quantile(unlist(ricepm), probs = c(.25, .5, .75))
```

but this gives me the wrong output (all 1's)

```
25% 50% 75% 
  1   1   1
```

A `dput(head(ricepm[, c(5, 5)]))` sample of my data

```r
structure(
    list(
        Antigua.and.Barbuda = 
            structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L), 
                .Label = 
                    c("0", "0,001255087", "0,001351049", "0,002179536", 
                    "0,002322295", "0,00352192", "0,003639649", "0,005203948", "0,005613623", 
                    "0,005899437", "0,0063163", "0,008692968", "0,010768326", "0,01815333", 
                    "0,022817923", "0,05455008", "0,076043772", "0,761972864", "1,167911482", 
                    "11,39171454", "17,55057703", "2,827338354", "3,180646314", "3,18612071", 
                    "3,519189594", "376,5666716", "4,22468796", "5,861801198", "572,3941286", 
                    "76,13680349"
                    ), 
                class = "factor"
            ), 
            Antigua.and.Barbuda.1 = 
                structure(
                    c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L),
                    .Label = 
                        c("0", "0,001255087", "0,001351049", 
                        "0,002179536", "0,002322295", "0,00352192", "0,003639649", "0,005203948", 
                        "0,005613623", "0,005899437", "0,0063163", "0,008692968", "0,010768326", 
                        "0,01815333", "0,022817923", "0,05455008", "0,076043772", "0,761972864", 
                        "1,167911482", "11,39171454", "17,55057703", "2,827338354", "3,180646314", 
                        "3,18612071", "3,519189594", "376,5666716", "4,22468796", "5,861801198", 
                        "572,3941286", "76,13680349"
                        ), 
                    class = "factor"
                )
        ), 
    row.names = 
        c("Afghanistan","Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina"), 
    class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: For the example shared it gives all the 0's because that is what the correct answer is. You need to use a higher `prob` value to get a non-zero value. `quantile(Z, 0.9)` gives you a non-zero value for example.

Comment: it seems your data are not numeric but factors. If you want to use quantile on them, you need to convert them to numeric, replacing comma by a dot beforehand. [This post on how to convert a factor to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/4137985) may be of help

Comment: @Cath Thanks! Running this seems to work, but I now get an output of only 0's. Do I need to tell R to exclude zeros in the matrix when counting the quantiles?

Comment: your data seems to contain a lot of zeros, probably more than 75% hence the quantile values...

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I'm getting the right results since the function appears to include 0's when calculating quantiles. Any tip on how to count the quantiles excluding 0's?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put all values of matrix `Z` inside a vector and take the quantiles from that you can do as follows:

```r
# Put values inside vector
Z_vec = as.vector(Z)

# Compute quantiles
 quantile(Z_vec, probs = c(.25, .5, .75))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this on my real data (a big matrix) but it gives me the following error: `Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected`

Comment: The `quantile()` function needs a vector as argument. Try to convert your dataframe to a matrix, then to a vector, and pass it as an argument. Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21178580/9477227).

Comment: I see, although doing this gives me `Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator`, maybe because it is a character vector? But when I try turning it into numeric, the entire matrix is filled with NA and 0's and I get `Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion`...

Comment: Could you share your data or another output example? See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: I added a new example above